# How could you write mod(a, x) with complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was looking around on the web and reading about the modulo function and different ways to define it, and I came across this:
“To get $\bmod(x,1)$, use $\frac12\Biggr({\log\big(e^{2\pi i\left(x-\frac12\right)}\big) \over \pi i}+1\Biggr)$, since $e^{2\pi i\left(x-\frac12\right)}$ has a period of 1.”
I was curious about was to generalize this for $\bmod(x,a)$, I played around with putting a in different parts of the function but wasn’t able to find something that works.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can just use mod$(x,a) = a$mod$(\frac xa,1)$.

Comment: Yep, that works, thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can simply use the identity
$$
\text{mod}(x,a) = a\text{ mod}(\tfrac xa,1)
$$
to convert the formula in the OP into a formula for mod$(x,a)$.